# Styled Receiver and Remote Display from the same sender app (Chromecast Android app)?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am building a **Chromecast Android sender app** that needs to have two receiver apps, one of type **Default / Styled Receiver App** and the other as **Remote Display**.

I am setting the `CastOptionsProvider` for my app in my `AndroidManifest.xml` as :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="com.myapp.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

**CastOptionsProvider.xml**

```
class CastOptionsProvider : OptionsProvider {

override fun getCastOptions(context: Context): CastOptions {
  // ... Other details
    return CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.remote_app_id))
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build()
  }   
//...other implementations
}
```

Since this class is not instantiated by me but by the SDK itself, how can I put receiver IDs for both the receiver apps here ?

`R.string.remote_app_id` is the place where I need to put receiver ids for both the apps.

Even if I create two options provider classes, one for each type, is it possible to put both the classes as `meta-data` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on Github at [Castvideo-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/66) and got the following reply from [Leon Nicholls](https://github.com/entertailion)

> Only one receiver ID is supported by the Cast SDK.
>   Also, we highly recommend that you don't use the Remote Display API anymore since it is deprecated.

So in conclusion, it's **not supported** as of now.