# Is CastRemoteDisplayLocalService usable in a Custom Receiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to create an app that can broadcast Android views on the Chromecast, and I thought I found something promising in [CastRemoteDisplayLocalService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.html). I created a simple test app but found the callback [onCreatePresentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.html#onCreatePresentation(android.view.Display)) was never called when I casted my device. After some searching I discovered it was because my application was not published as a Remote Display Application but a Custom Application Receiver from the Google Cast Developer Console.

Unfortunately when I try to create a new application from the console, Remote Display Application is not an option. After some searching, I came across [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052135/styled-receiver-and-remote-display-from-the-same-sender-app-chromecast-android) that said Remote Display API is now deprecated. There is an interface called [CastRemoteDisplayApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplayApi) which is marked as deprecated, but the classes I have been trying to use are not marked as such.

This leads me to wondering if CastRemoteDisplayLocalService and all other Remote Display classes not marked as deprecated are in fact deprecated and unusable, or if perhaps the functionality was shifted to work in a Custom Receiver by configuring it to accept remote displays.

This is what the relevant code looks like right now:

MainActivity.kt

```
private fun startCastService() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
    val notificationSettings = CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.NotificationSettings.Builder().setNotificationPendingIntent(pendingIntent).build()

    CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.startService(this, CastRemoteDisplayLocalServiceImpl::class.java, "2839EC8D", castDevice, notificationSettings, object : CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.Callbacks {
        override fun onRemoteDisplaySessionEnded(p0: CastRemoteDisplayLocalService?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoteDisplaySessionEnded")
        }

        override fun onRemoteDisplaySessionError(p0: Status?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoteDisplaySessionError")
        }

        override fun onRemoteDisplaySessionStarted(p0: CastRemoteDisplayLocalService?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoteDisplaySessionStarted")
        }

        override fun onServiceCreated(p0: CastRemoteDisplayLocalService?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceCreated")
        }
    })
}
```

CastRemoteDisplayLocalServiceImpl.kt

```
class CastRemoteDisplayLocalServiceImpl : CastRemoteDisplayLocalService() {

    val TAG = "CastRemoteDisplayLoc..."

    // This function gets called
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    }

    // This function does not get called
    override fun onCreatePresentation(p0: Display?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreatePresentation")
    }

    override fun onDismissPresentation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDismissPresentation")
    }
}
```

If there's a way with the Custom Application Receiver to get the onCreatePresentation callback that would solve this, I'm having difficulty finding it. If CastRemoteDisplayLocalService is in fact deprecated, is there another way to easily cast Android views to a Chromecast? Thanks!

Comment: We don't allow to create new Remote Display receiver app and support casting Android/IOS native view to Chromecast anymore, so those classes should be deprecated. I will follow up with android SDK team about the deprecation.

Comment: Hey @AnjaneeshRayapati , do we know why are these deprecated? There are some valid use-cases where I want to play multiple video, audio, and subtitles in parallel on the screen based on user input. It would be perfect if my Android app can control all this and just have Chromecast as a remote display. If remote display features are deprecated, is there a google recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: @cepiolot, did you make any headway with this?  Is it possible to use the Remote Display API connected to a Custom Receiver?

Comment: @KentMewhort after combing through Google bug reports, things seemed to indicate it was impossible, and that there were classes not marked deprecated that were in fact deprecated. Upon Anjaneesh's comment, it was confirmed. Take that comment as the answer; if he puts it as an answer I would mark it as accepted.